# Long touched on UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I already have a `UIButton` that increment a variable each time it's touched.
What I'd like to do now is when we stay touched on this `UIButton`, the variable increment it self each 0.5 seconds.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an action to the event `UIControlEventTouchDown` where you start a timer. On `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside` or `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` you stop the timer.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchedButton:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(releasedButton:) 
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

```
- (void)touchedButton:(id)sender {
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5f target:self 
                  selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)releasedButton:(id)sender {
    [self.timer invalidate];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: Actually it generates me a SIGABRT on UIApplicationMain when I do this :s

Comment: You did declare a property `timer` and an ivar `counter` right?

Comment: instead of counter++ I call a function that do my job (the fucntion was working before so i dont think the pb is there.
And yes, i added a NSTimer *timer to my class. but it didn't worked with "self." keyword so i only putted "timer"